# Installing Ros on unsupported platforms

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
we'd like to use ROS on a particular linux distribution (Wind River Linux), which is not in the supported OS list. Is it possible to compile from scratch all that is needed and use ROS on WRL?

Thanks in advace

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32200/installing-ros-on-unsupported-platforms/) by [hisdudeness](https://answers.ros.org/users/2212/hisdudeness/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having never used Wind River Linux, I would say to check [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation) for the "closest" OS and try starting there.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-11**:
To add support for a new platform a patch to rosdep is the most important thing to do: http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/developers_guide.html